# Developer plugin Wordpress Error instaling Debug bar

Tags: wordpress, plugins, developer-tools

I'm using the wordpress developer plugin, and getting some errors installing internal plugins. Using Localhost and MAMP

> Strict Standards: Declaration of Automattic_Developer_Empty_Upgrader_Skin::request_filesystem_credentials() should be compatible with WP_Upgrader_Skin::request_filesystem_credentials($error = false, $context = false, $allow_relaxed_file_ownership = false) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/developer/includes/class-empty-upgrader-skin.php on line 5
>   1

I find a lot of people with the same problem, but until now I didn't find any fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found this solution https://github.com/Automattic/developer/commit/69423f8a479a6d343e146a8b20d77b7f9ac66835.

You just to add 
$context = false, $allow_relaxed_file_ownership = false  in your class-empty-upgrader-skin.php file which you can locate in plugins/developer/include folder.